# What does Safari iCloud sync entail?

Tags: macos, icloud, safari, mobile-safari

Does it sync browsing history and safe passwords? Or just bookmarks and the reading list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safari sync is for browsing history, bookmarks and reading list.

Passwords are synchronised through Keychain, a separate option in iCloud.

Comment: I assume there is no way to cherry pick these features? Ie disable history sync but allow bookmarks and reading lists?